# Install aspent boilerplate package on new project get error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using new abp version template (Aspnet MVC+AngularJs) and want to add new class library project to it, when install abp nugget package (5.10.1) to it, got this error:

```
unable to find a version of 'Castle.Core.Asyncinterceptor' that is compatible with 'abp 5.10.1 constraint: CastleCore.AsyncInterceptor(>=2.0.21-alpha)'.
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by :
1: Install-Package Castle.Core.AsyncInterceptor -Version 2.0.21-alpha
2: Install-Package abp -Version 5.10.1